# Странные логи Nginx

Tags: nginx

обнаружил в логах nginx вот такую строку:

```
HEAD http://112.124.42.80:63435/ HTTP/1.1 200 0 -
```

Это нормальное поведение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слать head нормально. Если у браузера есть страница в кеше, то по head он прверяет не изменилась ли она.